# Pythonで特定の年の値だけを取得する方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: python, python3

2つのデータフレームを作って、特定の年の値を取得する方法が上手くいきません。

```
start = '1976-01-01' 
end =   '2020-01-01'
df1 = data.DataReader('^N225', 'yahoo',start, end)
```

df2の方には、

```
    year    小学校 中学校 高校
0   1976    13,312  5,743   6,420
1   1979    16,034  6,215   5,904
2   1982    20,023  9,609   7,331
3   1985    19,583  10,109  7,987
4   1988    17,368  10,417  8,791
```

のような1976年から3年ごとのデータがあります。

df1とdf2を比べて、df1を年でまとめて、df2の3年おきの西暦に合わせて値を取得したいのですが上手くいきません。

```
#df1
year = df1.index
price = df1['Adj Close']

df1 = df1.resample('Y').max()

#df2
df['小学校'] = df['小学校'].str.replace(',','').astype(np.int)
df['中学校'] = df['中学校'].str.replace(',','').astype(np.int)
df['高校'] = df['高校'].str.replace(',','').astype(np.int)
```

のように一応集計できるようにはし、

```
nikkei_year = []
nikkei_price =[]

for i in list(df2['year']):
    if i == df1['year]:
        nikkei_year.append(i)
        nikkei_price.append(df['price'])
```

とやってみたのですが、エラーがでてしまいました。

```
for i in list(df2['year']):
----> 5     if i == df['year']:
      6         nikkei_year.append(i)
      7         nikkei_price.append(df['price'])

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

解決方法をご教示頂けると助かります！

追記
df1の内容です。

```
High    Low Open    Close   Volume  Adj Close
Date                        
1976-01-05  4403.060059 4403.060059 4403.060059 4403.060059 0.0 4403.060059
1976-01-06  4449.700195 4449.700195 4449.700195 4449.700195 0.0 4449.700195
1976-01-07  4469.100098 4469.100098 4469.100098 4469.100098 0.0 4469.100098
1976-01-08  4485.770020 4485.770020 4485.770020 4485.770020 0.0 4485.770020
1976-01-09  4484.049805 4484.049805 4484.049805 4484.049805 0.0 4484.049805
```

Comment: コードはマークダウンで記入お願いします。（コードの前後に```を記入ください） また、エラーメッセージは全文掲載してください。（ユーザー名等は隠してもらって構いません）

Comment: 「df1 = data.DataReader('^N225', 'yahoo',start, end)」を実行した直後のdf1のデータを数行でよいので示してください。現状の質問では、df1に関する情報が全くないので、誰も回答できないと思います。

Comment: df1に入れる情報はこちらでしょう。[Nikkei 225 (^N225)](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EN225/history?p=%5EN225) 区切りの単位が日/週/月の3種類あるので、そのどれかは不明ですが。エラー内容としてはこれと類似でしょう。[ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() というエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52075/26370)

Comment: ありがとうございます。初めてこのサイトを使ったので、アドバイスありがたいです。訂正しました。

Answer (score 0):

以下のように2つの部分を変更してください。

変更元：

```
#df1
year = df1.index
price = df1['Adj Close']
```

変更後

```
#df1
df1['year'] = df1.index.year
df1['price'] = df1['Adj Close']
```

---

変更元：

```
    if i == df1['year]:
        nikkei_year.append(i)
        nikkei_price.append(df['price'])
```

変更後

```
    df = df1[df1['year'] == i]
    if not df.empty:
        nikkei_year.append(i)
        nikkei_price.append(df['price'])
```