# 積の形を用いた if 文の条件判定ができません

Tags: python

二分法を実行しようとして、次のようなコードを書いていたらエラーが出ました。エラーの原因とどのようにすればif文を積の形で使えるのかご教授願います。

```
import numpy as np
def func(t):
    return np.exp(x)-2*t-1
a = 1
b = 2

if (func(x)*func(b)) < 0.0:
    a =x
else:
    b = x
```

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: 質問のコードは「NameError: name 'x' is not define」のエラーが発生するはずですが、「ValueError」が発生したのは本当にこのコードですか？

Comment: おそらく、`x` は `numpy.ndarray` 型のインスタンスなのだと思います。エラーメッセージには `Use a.any() or a.all()` と表示されているので、`if (func(x)*func(b) < 0.0).any():` とでもすると良いかもしれません。(`any()` ではなく `all()` かもしれませんが)

Comment: @T K さん、上記コメントに有るように、提示されたソースコードは問題を再現出来ていません。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に修正や補足の追記をしてください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

おそらく現象や問題を誤解していると思われます。
問題は「積」や「積の形」なのではなく、metropolisさんのコメントにあるように扱っているデータ(`x`)がたぶん配列だからでしょう。

例えばこんな風に質問記事には書かれていない`x`の値を予め単一の値で設定しておけばエラーは発生しません。

```
import numpy as np

def func(t):
    return np.exp(x)-2*t-1

a = 1
b = 2
x = 0 #### x を何か単一の値(整数でも浮動小数点数でも可)で初期化しておく

if (func(x)*func(b)) < 0.0:
    a =x
else:
    b = x
```

おそらくJupyterNotebook/Lab等を使っていて、別のセルで`x`に配列データを設定していたとか、単純にPythonのインタプリタを使っていたとしても同様に`x`に配列データを設定後にインタプリタを終了・再起動せずに使い回して質問のスクリプトを入力した等の状況ではないでしょうか？

似たような感じでこんな記事もありますので参考に。
[ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() というエラーが出る](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/52075/26370)